# Can not create a basic logger in Perl

Tags: perl, log4perl

I am reading about `Log4Perl` from [perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/09/11/log4perl.html)
I am trying to follow the tutorial but got "lost" in the part `Logger Categories`.
I tried to follow the tutorial and did the following scripts:

I created a directory `Groceries` and inside I created a `pm` file as follows:
Food.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

package Groceries::Food;  

use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger);  

sub new {  
       my($class, $what) = @_;  
       my $logger = get_logger("Groceries::Food");  
       if(defined $what) {  
            $logger->debug("New food: $what");  
            return bless { what => $what }, $class;  
       }  
       $logger->error("No food defined");  
       return undef;  
}  
sub consume {  
        my($self) = @_;  
        my $logger = get_logger("Groceries::Food");  
        $logger->info("Eating $self->{what}");  
}
```

This is copy/paste from perl.com mentioned above.
Then in the same directory that `Groceries` directories is in (i.e. not in the same directory that `Food.pm` resides) I created another script as follows:
test_script.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

######### System initialization section ###  
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);  
my $food_logger = get_logger("Groceries");   
$food_logger->level($INFO);   

sub test_log(){  
        my $what = @_;  
        if(defined $what){  
                $food_logger->info("Defined:", $what);  
        }  
        else{  
                $food_logger->error("Nothing defined");  
        }  
}  

test_log();
```

But when I run the test script it does not work. I get:

`Log4perl: Seems like no initialization happened. Forgot to call init()?`

Also if I add:
`test_log("something");`

I get:

```
Too many arguments for main::test_log at testlogger.pl line 23, near ""something")" 
Execution of testlogger.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I followed the tutorial and modified the way it says at `listing 2: eat.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :levels);  

######### System initialization section ###  
my $food_logger = get_logger("Groceries::Food");  
$food_logger->level($INFO);  

#############Run it ###  
my $o = Groceries::Food->new("Chicken");  
$o->consume();  

####Application section ####  
package Groceries::Food;  

use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger);  

sub new {  
       my($class, $what) = @_;  
       my $logger = $food_logger;#get_logger("Groceries::Food");  
       if(defined $what) {  
            $logger->debug("New food: $what");  
            return bless { what => $what }, $class;  
       }  
       $logger->error("No food defined");  
       return undef;  
}  


sub consume {  
        my($self) = @_;  
        my $logger = $food_logger;#get_logger("Groceries::Food");  
        $logger->info("Eating $self->{what}");  
}
```

I still get `Log4perl: Seems like no initialization happened. Forgot to call init()?`

Comment: (1) I am not well versed with `Log::Log4Perl`, but please remove the `()` from the `test_log` declaration, unless you know exactly what *subroutine prototypes* are (You don't; this one states that `test_log` can't take any args). (2) The part of the article containing above code talks about inheriting configuration, and assumes that a `Groceries` class is fully set up to use Log4Perl. If you cover the `init` there, you don't have to repeat it in `Groceries::Food`. You don't seem to have prepared a `Groceries` class.

Comment: Information on how to initialize can be found in the FAQ -- [What's the easiest way to use Log4perl?](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html#f625e)

Comment: @toolic:But isn't `init` required when we provide a configuration file `Log::Log4perl->init("foo.conf");`? My configuration is in `######### System initialization section ###` in the script. Isn't it the same?

Comment: @devnull:Please see my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned appenders:

```
my $food_logger = get_logger("Groceries::Food");
$food_logger->level($INFO);

# Appenders
my $appender = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
    "Log::Dispatch::File",
    filename => "test.log",
    mode     => "append",
);

$food_logger->add_appender($appender);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the appenders as mentioned above should fix the error.

**Additional:**
Another option to simply get rid of this warning is to suppress the 'Log4perl: Seems like no initialization happened. Forgot to call init()?', by adding *qw(get_logger :nowarn)* to your Log4perl use statement:

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger :nowarn);
```

You can also run a check for initialization with *Log::Log4perl::initialized()*.
i.e.

```
print "Logger initialized\n" if ( Log::Log4perl::initialized() );
```

More details can be found here (Log4perl FAQ): http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/25575098/numer/3/nazwa/Log::Log4perl::FAQ

According to this documentation, the warning only appears once as a reminder to users not forget to initialize the logging system before using it.

Nevertheless, the first answer should be recommended.